# Sorting Excel Data

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

Right now the data looks like this:

```
COLUMN1                          COLUMN2                             COLUMN3

40 Broad Street                  Homeland Mechanical, LLC            Owner
Quincy, MA 02169
[blank]
Contact: Edward Sweeny
[blank]
Phone: (617) 845-5334
Alt Phone: (508) 901-0852
Fax: ***-****
[blank]
1311 Eastern Avenue              Better Comfort Systems, Inc.        President
Malden, MA 02148
[blank]
Contact: James Shaviro
[blank]
Phone: (781) 322-4099
Fax: ***-****
[blank]
```

The number of rows of data that each company takes up varies for a number of reasons. For example, the number of rows of the postal address can be more than two, e.g. if there is a P.O. box or apartment number. Also, as in the example above, companies may or may not have an "Alt Phone." So, the number of blank cells between cells with information in Column2 varies between seven and ten.

Need to rearrange to:

```
Column4                      Column5                Column6          Column7  
Business name                Contact Person          Street address    City and state    
Homeland Mechanical, LLC     Owner Edward Sweeny     40 Broad Street  Quincy, MA 02169    
Better Comfort Systems, Inc. President James Shaviro  1311 Eastern Avenue  Malden, MA 02148
```

Comment: You should not post real contact data.

Comment: the data is modified from the real contact data

Comment: What have you tried, or are you expecting someone to write the code for you?  Also, you show no examples of the output for some of your cases (eg. alt phone, multi-line addresses, etc).  I would go through line-by-line and extract the info as you go.  Maybe a collection of class objects, where the object is the Company and the properties are each of the items.  You can tell where a company's data starts by looking at Column 2.  And everything is labelled except for the Address and City/state/zip lines.

Comment: Good comment, Ron…….for me to poop on

Answer (score 0):

This will not completely solve your issue as it seems there is a different number of rows between each set of data, but a good start would be to select all cells from A1 to the bottom-right cell, copy and then Paste Special... Transpose.